# Center A Div Section

Tags: html, css

I am currently making a staff section on my website and i'm having trouble centering it. Anyone have a idea on how to center everything? It was originally made for four staff but I removed one and I can't seem to center everything correctly without messing everything up.

You can view it [here](http://zaxapps.com/nito/#team).

The HTML:

```
<!--Team-->
<section class="content-block white" id="team">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row animation" data-animation="fadeInUp"><!--By adding/removing class "animation" we enable/disable scroll animation of current element-->
        <h1>The Team</h1>
      <h2>The People Behind It All</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 animation" data-animation="fadeInLeft"><!--By adding/removing class "animation" we enable/disable scroll animation of current element-->
        <div class="team">
          <img src="img/Jordan.jpg" width="248" height="248" alt="Dexter Kirk"/>
          <h2>Jordan<br/>Berger</h2>
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <div class="social-icons si-icon-effect">
            <a href="#" class="si-icon fa fa-facebook">Facebook</a>
            <a href="#" class="im-icon-m icon-google-plus-ios">Google Plus</a>
            <a href="#" class="im-icon-l icon-instagram-ios">Instagram</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 animation" data-animation="fadeInLeft"><!--By adding/removing class "animation" we enable/disable scroll animation of current element-->
        <div class="team">
          <img src="img/Allan.jpg" width="248" height="248" alt="Richard Roe"/>
          <h2>Allan<br/>Maman</h2>
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <div class="social-icons si-icon-effect">
            <a href="#" class="si-icon fa fa-facebook">Facebook</a>
            <a href="#" class="im-icon-m icon-google-plus-ios">Google Plus</a>
            <a href="#" class="im-icon-l icon-instagram-ios">Instagram</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 animation" data-animation="fadeInRight"><!--By adding/removing class "animation" we enable/disable scroll animation of current element-->
        <div class="team">
          <img src="img/Cooper.jpg" width="248" height="248" alt="Anna Lobzenko"/>
          <h2>Cooper<br/>Weiss</h2>
          <h3>Title</h3>
          <div class="social-icons si-icon-effect">
            <a href="#" class="si-icon fa fa-facebook">Facebook</a>
            <a href="#" class="im-icon-m icon-google-plus-ios">Google Plus</a>
            <a href="#" class="im-icon-l icon-instagram-ios">Instagram</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

The CSS:

```
    /*Team*/
.team {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.team img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
}
.team h2,
.team h3 {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.team .social-icons {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.team .si-icon,
.team .im-icon-s,
.team .im-icon-m,
.team .im-icon-l {
    margin: 15px 33px 0 0;
    color: #999;
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
}
.team:hover img {
    border: 5px solid #fff;
}
.team .si-icon-effect .si-icon,
.team .si-icon-effect .im-icon-s,
.team .si-icon-effect .im-icon-m,
.team .si-icon-effect .im-icon-l {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #999;
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
}
.team:hover .si-icon,
.team:hover .im-icon-s,
.team:hover .im-icon-m,
.team:hover .im-icon-l {
    color: #666;
}
.team:hover .si-icon-effect .si-icon,
.team:hover .si-icon-effect .im-icon-s,
.team:hover .si-icon-effect .im-icon-m,
.team:hover .si-icon-effect .im-icon-l {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #666;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is change the column size on `col-lg-x` screen of each person container

`<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 animation"...>` to be  `<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 animation"...>`

Answer (score 1):

I made some change on your code, Check this:

```
<!--Team-->
<section class="content-block white" id="team">
<div class="container">
<div class="row animation" data-animation="fadeInUp"><!--By adding/removing class "animation" we enable/disable scroll animation of current element-->
    <h1>The Team</h1>
  <h2>The People Behind It All</h2>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 animation" data-animation="fadeInLeft"><!--By adding/removing class "animation" we enable/disable scroll animation of current element-->
    <div class="team">
      <img src="img/Jordan.jpg" width="248" height="248" alt="Dexter Kirk"/>
      <h2>Jordan<br/>Berger</h2>
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <div class="social-icons si-icon-effect">
        <a href="#" class="si-icon fa fa-facebook">Facebook</a>
        <a href="#" class="im-icon-m icon-google-plus-ios">Google Plus</a>
        <a href="#" class="im-icon-l icon-instagram-ios">Instagram</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 animation" data-animation="fadeInLeft"><!--By adding/removing class "animation" we enable/disable scroll animation of current element-->
    <div class="team">
      <img src="img/Allan.jpg" width="248" height="248" alt="Richard Roe"/>
      <h2>Allan<br/>Maman</h2>
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <div class="social-icons si-icon-effect">
        <a href="#" class="si-icon fa fa-facebook">Facebook</a>
        <a href="#" class="im-icon-m icon-google-plus-ios">Google Plus</a>
        <a href="#" class="im-icon-l icon-instagram-ios">Instagram</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 animation" data-animation="fadeInRight"><!--By adding/removing class "animation" we enable/disable scroll animation of current element-->
    <div class="team">
      <img src="img/Cooper.jpg" width="248" height="248" alt="Anna Lobzenko"/>
      <h2>Cooper<br/>Weiss</h2>
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <div class="social-icons si-icon-effect">
        <a href="#" class="si-icon fa fa-facebook">Facebook</a>
        <a href="#" class="im-icon-m icon-google-plus-ios">Google Plus</a>
        <a href="#" class="im-icon-l icon-instagram-ios">Instagram</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```